# Angular 4 - How do you know which order to place your imports?

Tags: angular

How am I supposed to know the order to place my Angular imports?

Answer (score 1):

With angular, Only the order of **`providers`** matters, for directives,  exported components, or pipes it doesn't matter, because conflicts result in errors.